# SharePoint navigation design issue

Tags: windows-server-2008, sharepoint

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 x64 and Windows Server 2008 x64. I have setup a site with template publishing portal. I have grant anonymous access to all the site.

I want to design a two layered navigation solution for the site. And I want to know if there is any advice or document for me to follow-up in order to setup the navigation solution.

In more details, my requirement is, (1) in the top global nagivation area, I want to display top categories (car, computer and book) (2) on the left navigation area, I want to display the sub-category for the selected top category from top global navigation area, for example, if computer is selected, I want to display sub-category on left navigation area, like laptop/server/netbook (3) when user clicks a sub-category on the left navigation area, I want to expand sub-category to specific commodity list on the left navigation area (e.g. expand laptop to ThinkPad T60/T61/T400, 3 expanded links on the left navigation area), and when use select a specific commodity, like ThinkPad T60, on the main display area the specific page for the commodity will be displayed -- at the same time, the left side navigation area still remains the same (i.e. display sub-category laptop/server/netbook with expanded ThinkPad T60/T61/T400 for laptop sub-category).

Any documents or advice for such solution? Is it hard or not in SharePoint Server 2007?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with SharePoint. Under WebsiteSettings you'll find a Option "Look and Feel" >> "Navigation" where you can define the navigation of the actual website (SPWeb).

There you can configure a global navigation and a local navigation. In the standard design the global navigation is the horizontal one and the local navigation is the vertical one.

For the global navigation you have two options:

- Show same navigation as on the parent website
- Show only child-websites of the actual site

The local navigation settings offer three options:

- Show the same menu as the navigation of the parent website
- Show only child-websites and websites on the same level
- Show only child-websites

So in you case for the horizontal navigation you would select the first option on each of your websites. Showing everywhere the navigation of the parent website.

For the local navigation it is a little bit more complicate. On the websites car, computer and books you select the last option. So if you click on computer in the global navigation you will only see laptop/server/netbook on the local navigation. On the websites laptop/server/netbook you would select the second option, so all children of a selected website (e.g. laptop) are shown but server and netbook are also still visible.